# Linq complex queries C#

Tags: c#, linq

i have this:

```cs
int item = particleEdges.ElementAt(i).Key;
Point3 hashPoint = particleEdges[item][j].hashEdge;

var hashList = particleEdges 
    .Where(p => p.Value.Any(q => q.hashEdge == hashPoint))
    .Select(r => r.Key != item)
    .ToList();
```

How to exclude "item" from hashList? Broke my head. Linq doesn't want to open to me.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO!  Just a note, given that you've mentioned particles - is this in performance-critical code (e.g. a particle system?).  If it is, you want to avoid using LINQ entirely and hand-roll your stuff.

Comment: Replace `Select` with `Where`

Comment: No, speed is not important to me here. I want flexible beautiful code. And just learn Linq. Speed ​​will be needed at other stages of working with particles. And there I will no longer need Linq. I just need to go through polygons and build connections.

Comment: Some more information required for particleEdges data type and sample data if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hashList = particleEdges
    .Where(p => p.Value.Any(q => q.hashEdge == hashPoint))
    .Where(r => r.Key != item)
    .Select(s => s.Key)
    .ToList();
```